# How to add a tag class to database using Migrations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I Just want to create these classes and then use the migration to update my database . My question is :

How to make PostTagMap class ? and here is the photo of the classes relation ..

[Classes Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6TY0.jpg)

```
public class Post
{
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Title
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string ShortDescription
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Meta
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string UrlSlug
    { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Published
    { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime PostedOn
    { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime? Modified
    { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Tag> Tags
    { get; set; }
}
```

and here is the tag class :

```
 public class Tag
{
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string UrlSlug
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Post> Posts
    { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not using [tag:asp-classic] I'd wager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need to create a PostTagMap class, the many many relationship is already handled by your navigation Properties in your case `public virtual IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }` for Post class and `public virtual IList<Post> Posts { get; set; }` for Tag Class. This will be handled once you run update-database